# Can't disable my Ipv6 in my ubuntu

Tags: linux, hadoop, ipv6, nano

I'm installing hadoop on my linux right now, so far I've installed and extracted hadoop, and set up my Java Home variable. I'm trying to disable my ipv6, but so far when I tried to save changes, it shows the following:

This is my command:

```
nano /etcl.systct.conf
```

Can this command work:

```
error writing /etc/sysct.conf: permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run command with `sudo`

Ex: `sudo nano /etcl.systct.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it as superuser, add sudo when the permission is denied. Change the file permission using chown.

```
    sudo chown 755 file name
    sudo command file_name
```